# Change the value of "Show entries"- dropdown of datatables: "iDisplayLength" is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have been trying to edit the dropdown options of "Show entries" of my datatable. The default is 10, i.e. at the page contains 10 rows but I want to show all rows in one page at first. My code is given below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#multiServiceJobTable').dataTable().columnFilter({
                     aoColumns: [
                                null,
                                {type: "select"},
                                {type: "select"},
                                {type: "select"},
                                {type: "select"},
                                {type: "select"},
                                {type: "select"},
                                {type: "select"}
                            ],
                             aLengthMenu: [
                                          [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                                          [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
                                          ],
                             iDisplayLength: -1
                });

                $('#multiServiceJobTable tfoot tr').insertAfter($('#multiServiceJobTable thead tr'));
        });
```

Its a very simple table. I am using datatables version 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed the options in the wrong order :

```
$('#multiServiceJobTable').dataTable({
   aLengthMenu: [
     [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
     [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
   ],
   iDisplayLength: -1
}).columnFilter({
   aoColumns: [
     null,
     {type: "select"},
     {type: "select"},
     {type: "select"},
     {type: "select"},
     {type: "select"},
     {type: "select"},
     {type: "select"}
   ]
});
```

As you have it now, you pass `aLengthMenu` etc to the `columnFilter` plugin, not the dataTable itself.